# Font Awesome icons do not appear in ModernCV

Tags: moderncv, ubuntu, fontawesome

I am trying to compile my ModernCV résumé with Font Awesome icons.

This is the LaTeX which I'm attempting to compile:

```
\documentclass[10pt,sans,letterpaper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\moderncvicons{awesome} % this should force font-awesome icons

\name{First}{Last}
\title{Title Here}
\email{email@example.com}
\homepage{example.com}
\social[linkedin]{LinkedIn}
\social[github]{GitHub}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

When I am on Arch Linux, everything works as expected; the icons which appear are the Font Awesome ones. However, when I am using Ubuntu 12.04, the document compiles (there are no errors) but the icons seem to fallback to the MarVoSym set. This also seems to happen in Ubuntu 16.04 and I am not sure why this is happening.

Here are the commands which I use to set up my LaTeX environment:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa -y
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra
mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/
wget https://launchpad.net/moderncv/trunk/1.5.1/+download/moderncv-1.5.1.zip
unzip moderncv-1.5.1.zip
mv moderncv/ ~/texmf/tex/latex/
mktexlsr
```

I can also verify that Font Awesome is installed because this compiles and shows up properly:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\name{First}{Last}

\begin{document}
\faLinkedin
\end{document}
```

Finally, the command I am using to compile is `pdflatex <filename>`.

EDIT:

I checked the log output and I found these offending lines:

```
WARNING: to use the awesome icon set, please use XeTeX or LuaTeX to compile you
r document; switching to the marvosym icon set.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
```

EDIT2:

I put `\listfiles` on the top of my file and ran `pdflatex` three times. This is the filelist I obtained:

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/01/19 v6377 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolororange.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 color scheme: orange
moderncviconsawesome.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r icons: awesome
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
DentonLiuResume.out
DentonLiuResume.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
 ***********
```

Comment: Can you show the log file of the failing instance?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I found out that it's telling me to use either XeTeX or LuaTeX. Is there any way to force `pdflatex` to use to use either of these?

Comment: @DentonL `xelatex` and `lualatex` are alternatives to `pdflatex` they should all be on your system, if you use `xelatex <filename>` rather than `pdflatex <filename>` on the command line that will compile with `xelatex` but you should (unless I'm misremembering) be able to get the `fontawesome` fonts using `pdflatex`

Comment: I ran `lualatex <file>` and it gave me ``LaTeX Error: File `luatexbase.sty` not found.``

Comment: I did run your example file with `pdflatex` without problems. But you seem to have a rather old TeX system.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum, I ran `pdflatex --version` and it told me I was running version `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16`. I will try upgrading to a newer version, though!

Comment: I upgraded it so that I'm now using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)`. However, it doesn't show up and I get the same message telling me to use XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: You said that you got moderncv from https://launchpad.net/moderncv/trunk/1.5.1/+download/moderncv-1.5.1.zip you'll find the latest version of [`moderncv`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) (2.0.0) at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv

Comment: Yep, that seemed to fix it! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my current MiKTeX I get the following list of packages and version numbers:

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
fancyhdr.sty    2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2016/05/14 v2.6a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2016/05/14 v2.6a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2016/05/14 v2.6a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter compatibility patches
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
moderncvheadi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 1
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolororange.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: orange
moderncviconsawesome.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: awesome
fontawesome.sty    2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons
fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  342789.out
  342789.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
ufontawesometwo.fd    2016/05/22 Font definitions for U/fontawesometwo.
 ***********
```

There are a lot of differences to yours, as you can see.

please update your system.  Then should `fontawesome` be able to run with `pdflatex` just as it did on my current system ....

Please see that the current version of class `moderncv` is 2.0 and not yor 1.5.1. As far as I remember was there a problem with fontawesome.  So please update your complete TeX distribution.  Because there are some changes in `moderncv` in version 2 it could be that you receive some warnings, but that is at last no problem ...

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading from version 1.5.1 of `moderncv` to version `2.0` fixed it! Thanks so much for your help!